# repair/recovery tool for Western Digital Elements (1TB)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

My Hard Disk Drive just got corrupted due to electricity fluctuation. When I plug my Western Digital Elements, It ask me if I want to format it or not... I can't see my files or even the capacity of my disk from it's properties.

Is there any solution you would suggest? looking for a software that can give me access to my files. I just need to copy it then I can retire my Drive and will buy a new one...

Thanks!

Comment: +1 and I hope there is software, but I've always taken my HDD to a recovery specialist.

Comment: a simple chk disk fixed the problem ;) I now have my files back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 main programs

- http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html
- http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

these are both included on SystemRescueCD

- http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page

I mainly use ddrescue, even works if some of the heads have faild

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happen to me. With much trial and error I found that the USB connecting jack at the Elements end is not making properly. Try to enter the jack half way. If the drive light comes on wait and see if spinning starts and the arm moving is felt. If so see the drive is recognized and files are able to reed. In my case I cleaned the both ends with a sharp safety pin. Specially the drives end and drive socket projected pins with grooves.If these groove end plastics are not letting cable to connect properly or only power is connected without data lines this can happen. My solution if this is the case is to expand slightly the drive end jack, end metal cover joining parts slightly outwards to get a little good pressure on the drive side male projection part.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the upper metal cover by unscrewing 4 screws on left and right edges.
- Remove the cover to expose the back side of the motherboard PCB showing 5 or 6 screws.
- Unscrew all of them and pick up the PCB.
- Use an obsolete toothbrush and adequate PCB cleaning thinner and rub the three IC solder bases quite gently together with all metal points on the board. Take utmost care while rubbing and cleaning.
- Dry the cleaned surface with a dryer and screw back all screws and cover the upper part as well.
- Plug the hard drive in and power it up.

In more than 60% of cases, hard drive problems are fixed and it starts functioning. Copy your data off the drive at your earliest convenience.